# How is final topology the "dual" of initial topology?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) page of Wikipedia which said

> The **dual notion** (of initial topology) is the final topology, which for a given family of functions mapping to a set $X$ is the finest topology on $X$ that makes those functions continuous.

Below are their definitions that I take from Wikipedia.

- Given a set $X$ and an indexed family $(Y_{i}, \tau_i)_{i \in I}$ of topological spaces with functions $f_{i}: X \rightarrow Y_{i}$. The [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology#Definition) $\tau$ on $X$ induced by the collection $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is the *coarsest* topology on $X$ such that each
  $$
  f_{i}:(X, \tau) \to (Y_{i}, \tau_i)
  $$
  is continuous. It follows that $\{f_i^{-1} (O_i) \mid i\in I, O_i \in \tau_i\}$ is a [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Definition) of $\tau$.
- Given a set $X$ and an indexed family $(Y_{i}, \tau_i)_{i \in I}$ of topological spaces with functions $f_{i}: X \rightarrow Y_{i}$. The [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology#Definition) $\tau$ on $X$ induced by the collection $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ is the *finest* topology on $X$ such that each
  $$
  f_{i}: (Y_{i}, \tau_i) \to (X, \tau)
  $$
  is continuous. It follows that $\tau =\{O \subset X \mid f_i^{-1}(O) \in \tau_i \quad \forall i\in I\}$.

Besides the "coarsest/finest", could you explain how they are "dual" of each other?

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into it, but, you can read about [opposite categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_category) to get the gist.

Comment: Basically, the arrows go in the other way. I don't think this "duality" is very formal, it's more of an intuition that those two constructions are kind of mirroring each other, one with arrows going out of $X$, and one with the arrows going in.